# LAHF (load AH with lower order byte of the flag register)

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

Using `LAHF` the AH register can be loaded with the higher order byte of the flag register.

The flag register has 7 undefined registers. I have two questions:

1. Are the undefined bits considered in the LAHF operation?
2. If the are considered,are the undefined bits in the flag register taken as binary 1 or binary 0?

Comment: “undefined” means that the bits are reserved for future instruction set extensions. They should not be relied upon in any way. That is, do not assume that the undefined bits are set and do not assume that they are unset.

Comment: so they are not considered while executing the lahf instruction?

Comment: They might be if your code is executing on a more recent processor (the `LAHF` instruction would naturally see its meaning extended to include the copy of these bits). **You** should not write any code that can behave observationally different whether they are or they aren't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flags SF, ZF, AF, PF, and CF are copied to AH bits 7, 6, 4, 2, and 0, respectively. The contents of the remaining bits 5, 3, and 1 of AH is generally accepted as undefined. This is true if you look at the older instruction sets, for example the [80386](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/LAHF.htm) one.

However the more recent **[IA-32 Intel® Architecture Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)** spells out explicit bit states for LAHF:

```
Operation
AH ← EFLAGS(SF:ZF:0:AF:0:PF:1:CF);
```